# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tagsInput'

Tags: jquery

My php code is like

```
<div class="field">                 
    <label  style="float: none;">Recipients (by username):</label>
    <?=form_error('to')?>
    <input id="to" name="to" type="text" value="<?=$form_to?>" class="taglist"  />
</div>
```

I have included **jquery.tagsinput.css**

and I have also added the script

```
$('.taglist').tagsInput({
        'height':'27px',
        'width':'400px',
        'defaultText':'add recepient',
    });
```

But i am getting the following error in console :

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tagsInput'**

Any ideas.. what could have been the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Have you added the javascript source file?

Comment: Importing a css file won't magically add a js function to jquery.

Comment: It needs `tagsInput` js file too.

Comment: @limelights my silly mistake. i have included the js file and things are working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look like you forgot to add tagsinput js script..(and obivously jquery.js)

here add this in `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
```

OR

if you have downlaoded the file then.. give proper path to your taginputs js file..

```
<script src="path/to/your/file/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
```